# Squeezedet Keras

Tags: python, keras, importerror

I am trying to run the following object detector,
https://github.com/omni-us/squeezedet-keras

The folder hierarchy is as follows:

squeezedet-keras

```
   -> experiments
        -> kitti

   -> scripts
        -> train.py

   -> main
        -> model
            -> squeezeDet
            -> imagenet.h5
```

Now from squeezedet-keras/experiments/kitti, I run the command:

```
>>python ../../scripts/train.py --init ../../main/model/imagenet.h5
```

The 'train.py' file begins with this line:

```
from main.model.squeezeDet import  SqueezeDet
```

This gives the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "../../scripts/train.py", line 9, in
>
> from main.model.squeezeDet import  SqueezeDet
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

I am running this from a virtualenv, and my default python is 3.7.2, on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: So, you have followed all the instructions and tried to run the above command and got this error message? It seems that your python can find `train.py` but not `imagenet.h5`. Are you sure it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter is having a hard time of loading the project's modules.

The module loader will only recognize folders that:

- Are inside `{venv_folder}/lib/python{version}/site-packages/` --- they were likely installed with `pip install ...` or `python setup.py install`
- Are in the current working directory
- Are pointed by `PYTHONPATH` env var

The easiest way to solve this is to set the env var:

```sh
cd working_dir/
source /path/to/my/venv/
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/squeezedet-keras
python ../../scripts/train.py --init ../../main/model/imagenet.h5
```

Another way is to just navigate to the project's folder before executing the scripts:

```sh
cd /path/to/squeezedet-keras
source /path/to/my/venv/
python scripts/train.py --init main/model/imagenet.h5
```